Missing trait implementation even though there is one
Consider the following example:
trait HasMouth {
   fn speak(&self);
}

trait Animal : HasMouth {}

trait Human : Animal {
   fn speak(&self) {
       println!("Hey there! I'm a human!");
   }
}

impl<T: Human + Animal> HasMouth for T {

}

This code will not compile:
   |
   |     fn speak(&self);
   |     ---------------------- `speak` from trait
...
   | impl<T: Human + Animal> HasMouth for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `speak` in implementation

However, the compiler should know that I'm implementing the trait for any type that implements Human, which provides an implementation for speak, so it should not be required to provide one here.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Human::speak and HasMouth::speak are not the same function. Furthermore, the impl is completely unnecessary since anything that impls Human already impls HasMouth.

@drewtato The impl is not unnecessary: if it would compile, it would mean that something that impls Human and Animal does not need to impl HasMouth.

Every trait function is different from every other trait function, regardless of whether they happen to share a name, so Human::speak() has no interaction with HasMouth::speak(). It would be possible to explicitly delegate from HasMouth to Human:
impl<T: Human + Animal> HasMouth for T {
    fn speak(&self) {
        <T as Human>::speak(self)
    }
}

However, in the big picture, it looks like you are trying to create a class hierarchy using traits. This will not work, because traits don't really inherit things from other traits. Also, you can only have one of your impl<...> HasMouth for T; if you add a trait Cat: Animal like trait Human, you will get a conflict when trying to implement for both:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `HasMouth`
  --> src/main.rs:23:1
   |
18 | impl<T: Human + Animal> HasMouth for T {
   | -------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
23 | impl<T: Cat + Animal> HasMouth for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation

You should not think of traits as superclasses. Rather, a well-designed trait defines something you can do with a type. So, HasMouth is a good trait (though it should be called Speak, because traits should be named after the operation they support — verbs not nouns — when possible), but Human and Animal are probably not, because they aren't about specific operations.
You should define traits for recurring operations, and then use trait bounds to require types to implement the traits that are needed for the code using the type. This is flat, not hierarchical.
